# how to save the state of a page after navigating away from it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering how to save the variables of a page when you navigate away from it and then navigate back without using Navigator.pop(context). I've created a simple version using the starting code

here is the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Page01.dart';
import 'MyHomePage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        '/first': (context) => const Page01(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here is the main home page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/first');
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('change page'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

and finally here is page01

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page01 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page01({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page01> createState() => _Page01State();
}

class _Page01State extends State<Page01> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('change page'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the from the MainHomePage code, Ifound a tutorial using with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

but the code I currently have still resets the counter variable.

I think there is something to do with a pageview widget but im unsure where or how to implement it.

thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop from `Page01` instead of pushing new route.

```dart
child: InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pop(context); //this
  },
  child: Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Text('change page'),
  ),
),
```

In future you may use state-management property like riverpod/bloc.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do it with with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin?

Comment: Basicially, in my app, (the above code is not it) I have a drawer in my app bar with listtiles to navigate around the app. and Navigator.pop(context doesn't seem to be working from inside the drawer

Comment: While it is going to new route, I don't know if it is possible without some global/route_args/state-management.. 1st `pop` will close the drawer, you can pop again to go back to previous page